# Comparison of two ways of looping in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review

I wrote a small script to demonstrate two ways of looping in Python: with and without using the index. I want to know which way is better. Please see the example:

```
####################################################################################################
# Imagine there is some registration info of some people and their nationalities
# Stored in a Python dictionary
people_nationality_info = {'person_1': 'UK',
                           'person_2': 'Iceland',
                           'person_3': 'France',
                           'person_4': 'Spain',
                           'person_5': 'Norway',
                           'person_6': 'Sweden',
                           'person_7': 'Denmark',
                           'person_8': 'Germany'}

# Now some people are present at a meeting
# and also there is a new person "person_x" who is not currently registered
people_at_the_meeting = ['person_3','person_5','person_6','person_x']

# Now check the nationality of each person at the meeting

# method 1:
for i in range(len(people_at_the_meeting)):
    if people_at_the_meeting[i] in people_nationality_info:
        j = list(people_nationality_info.keys()).index(people_at_the_meeting[i])
        print(people_at_the_meeting[i],list(people_nationality_info.values())[j],sep=" : ")
    else:
        people_nationality_info[people_at_the_meeting[i]] = input("Where are you from?")
        
# method 2:
for person in people_at_the_meeting:
    if person in people_nationality_info:
        print(person,people_nationality_info[person],sep=" : ")
    else:
        people_nationality_info[person] = input("Where are you from?")
```

When I was given this task, I wrote method 1 straight away. But some time later I realized it can be done using method 2.

I wrote both methods. Both ways work, but I would like to know which is better, more Pythonic, closer to Python's best practices?

My first programming language is R, and due to the way I was trained, my intuition is always to use index.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You stated "_I wrote method 1_". Are you the author or maintainer of the code in _method 2_?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I wrote both, I have edited the post to clarify this. I am new to Code Review. From your comment, I think I have to always make it clear in any posts that I am the author or I have the permission from the author?

Comment: Correct - this site is for reviewing code you wrote and/or maintain. [“_For licensing, moral, and procedural reasons, we cannot review code written by other programmers._”](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). [There are multiple reasons why Code Review has the restriction that the code has to be your own code.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1295/120114).

Comment: Use method 2, not the index. Better yet, decompose method 2 into two loops based on set intersection

Comment: But this really seems theoretical, and theoretical/stub code is off-topic for code review; the same for best-practices. If you can show the whole program (or at least more of it), then we don't need to rely on our imaginations as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loops...

...if you only need the elements:

```
for element in collection:
    ...
```

...if you need the elements and their indices:

```
for idx, element in enumerate(collection):
    ...
```

...if you only need the indices (do you? that's rare):

```
for idx in range(len(collection)):
    ...
```

---

Your case is the first since you never use the index for any purpose other than accessing the element of the collection you're iterating over.